# Nodejs: Can't post image with string fields in express and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

New to Express and Mongoose. I am using `mutler` to upload image with `post` request along with some other `String` and `Number` data. When I upload only the image with postman, it appears in the designated location but, when I send the strings, it shows this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
```

For now, I have mentioned the photo as optional.This is my schema:

```
const menuItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    price: Number,
    category: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['veg', 'non-veg']
    },
    weight: Number,
    photo: {type: String, required: false},
    ingredients: [String]
});

const MenuItem = mongoose.model('MenuItem', menuItemSchema);
```

And this is the route. I have defined mutler properties in this route file:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'images/menuItem')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix + '.jpg')
    }
  });

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  const allowedFileTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'];
  if(allowedFileTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {:
    cb(null, false);
  }
}

const upload = multer({ storage, fileFilter })

router.post('/', upload.single('photo'),(req, res, next) => {
    const photo = req.file.filename;
    const name = req.body.name;
    const price = req.body.price;
    const category = req.body.category;
    const weight = req.body.weight;
    const ingredients = req.body.ingredients
    
    const newMenuItemData = {name, price, category, weight, ingredients, photo}
    const newMenuItem = new MenuItem(newMenuItemData);
    newMenuItem.save()
        .then(menuItem => res.json({'message': 'Item added!'}))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

As you can see, the photo is optional, so how do I add other fields when the photo is not required? Also, I got the error when trying with postman.

Comment: It looks like `req.file` is `undefined`. How did you configure the request in Postman?

Comment: Added the image as `form-data` in body, made the request. Then added the other fields as raw - JSON in body and made the request. I tried these two ways.

Comment: The request's data type can be either `form-data` or `json`. you can add the string as a field in the form-data.

Comment: const photo = req.file.filename; change this line to 

const photo = req.file && req.file.filename;

Comment: @IleshPatel it worked. But is not `req.file` and `req.file.filename` depict the same thing?

Comment: when you try to use req.file.filename and your req.file is undefined, your code will try to access filename from undefined. when you add req.file && req.file.filename , you are making sure, code only access filename if req.file is not undefined.